# Loop through array to get field values of a document in firestore using android/kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I want to be able to access the field values of my collection,but I am not able to do this in the for loop.

I have attached the code I tried and screenshot below.

In the below code str is the name in document(eg:sgjj as in screenshot which is being got)

The screenshot of firestore database:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvIzk.png)

Code I tried:

```js
class HostActivityScreen : AppCompatActivity(),HostAdapter.OnItemCheckListener {
    var currentSelected:ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
    override fun onItemCheck(item: String) {

        currentSelected.add(item)

    }

    override fun onItemUncheck(item: String) {

        currentSelected.remove(item)

    }
    
  for(str in currentSelected){
    print(str)
    var id: String = ""
    var gamingname:String=""
                mFirestore.collection("AllUsers").document(str).get().addOnCompleteListener(OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot> { task ->
      if (task.isSuccessful) {
          val docs:DocumentSnapshot= task.result!!
          print(docs.getData())
          if(docs!=null){
                    id =task.result!!.data!!.get("gaminguserid").toString()
                   gamingname = task.result!!.data!!.get("gaminname").toString();
                        }

                              }
    })
  }

}
```

The error it shows is:

```
kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
    at HostActivityScreen$onCreate$1$5.onSuccess(HostActivityScreen.kt:120)
    at HostActivityScreen$onCreate$1$5.onSuccess(HostActivityScreen.kt:31)
    at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzn.run(Unknown Source)
```

line 120 is:

```js
id= documentSnapshot.getString("gaminguserid")!!
```

line 31 is:

```js
class HostActivityScreen : AppCompatActivity(),HostAdapter.OnItemCheckListener {
```

Screenshot of my debug screen(does not enter addonsucesslistener):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzOT8.png)

Neither of above code works,i can see the str value is got but it does not enter in the addonsuccesslistener or the addoncompletelistener loop.Why does this happen.How can i acess the field values?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Are there errors? Observed behaviors?

Comment: What's wrong with this code? Please also responde with @.

Comment: @AlexMamo  I have updated my above code with the error/debug screenshot

Comment: @DougStevenson  I have updated my above code with the error/debug screenshot.

Comment: Just try to avoid loop and give document name manually to debug

Comment: @sansiad What is the value of `str` inside `document(str)`?

Comment: @Niyas I can access the value when its not in the for loop,but in the for loop it does not run.

Comment: @AlexMamo currentselected is an arraylist which stores values of users selected.So for example if I select a user named shawn and ralph then currentselected=["shawn","ralph"] .So str is shawn then ralph.I want to loop in the array,whats the right way as this is not working.

Comment: Include full class, where the get function is called

Comment: @Niyas I have updated my code 2 with the required currentselected array in the class ...There is a list which is shown and on checking items they get added in currentselected arraylist which is prints the selected values on debugging.But then the for loop it does not enter the loop.

Comment: I wanted to say it enters the for loop with the correct values but it does enter addonsuccesslistener nor the addonfailurelistener

Comment: What is the right way to loop through an arraylist element to access the value in firestore?In this case it stops at the addonsucesslistener and then goes back to for loop

Comment: Is get function called from activity or fragment

Comment: @Niyas The firestore get function is called from the activity.But I have updated only required code of the activity in my question.The other part of code is related to showing a list of users who loggedin using recyclerview.

Comment: @DougStevenson Is it not possible to access a firebase document name using a variable?as it works if I use the name,but does not work if I loop it through variable in for loop.

Comment: I figured it out.It was a silly mistake which was overlooked. var id: String = "" and 
var gamingname:String="" have to be declared inside the firestore as the documentsnapshot value cannot be accessed from outside the database listener.So now my code works fine. :-)

Answer (score -1):

Below code that works for me:

```js
mFirestore.collection("AllUsers").document(str).get().addOnSuccessListener(OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot> {documentSnapshot->
  var id: String = ""
  var gamingname:String=""
  if(documentSnapshot.exists()){
        id= documentSnapshot.getString("gaminguserid")!!                                  
        gamingname=documentSnapshot.getString("gaminname")!!
   }else
   {                                      
        Toast.makeText(this@HostActivityScreen,"Document does not exist", 
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
   }
                               
}).addOnFailureListener(OnFailureListener { e->
val error=e.message                             
Toast.makeText(this@HostActivityScreen,"Error:"+error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
})
```